# Table cell height by UITextView where content alignment is NSTextAlignmentJustified

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios6, uitextview

I have a UITextView where content is aligned by NSTextAlignmentJustified. In the **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** add this text view to cell content view and change frame according it's content by

```
UITextView *commentsTextView = (UITextView *)[self getCommentField:comment];
[cell.contentView addSubview:commentsTextView];
CGRect tempFrame = commentsTextView.frame;
tempFrame.size.height = commentsTextView.contentSize.height;
commentsTextView.frame = tempFrame;
```

So far, so good. Now, how to detect contentSize of that view for **heightForRowAtIndexPath:**? 
I tried

```
NSString *comment = [[self.allComments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"commentText"];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(315.0f, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize size = [comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]
                  constrainedToSize:constraintSize
                      lineBreakMode:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
```

Also I tried **lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping** and so. But cell height is always smaller when text is long, because there seems to be no way how to coumpute size of **justified** text (because of the white spaces in the middle of text). Font is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i got it. UITextView has 8 pixels insect from each side, co my **CGSizeMake(315.0f, MAXFLOAT);** have to be **CGSizeMake(299.0f, MAXFLOAT);**